# Determining Derived Class Type At Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a generic method with a new() constraint.  I have a call to this method with an abstract type which, of course, won't compile. I wish to keep the call generic, but was hoping I could determine at runtime what the derived class is so as to satisfy the compiler. The call would look something like this:

```
var result = MyGenericMethod<FindDerivedClass(myAbstractClass)>();
```

I tried typeof() but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a generic method with a new() constraint. I have a call to this method with an abstract type which, of course, won't **compile**. I wish to keep the call generic, but was hoping I could determine at runtime what the derived class is so as to satisfy **the compiler**.

It's not the compilation, but rather the actual **semantics** you need to worry about. You have a method with a `new()` constraint - this suggests that the method needs to instantiate an object of the `T` it is passed. You want to pass an abstract class as the `T` - but what would this mean? What should the generic method do when it wants to instantiate?

You need to decide the answers to these questions: If the method doesn't need to instantiate a `T`, why does it have a `new()` constraint? If it does need to instantiate a `T`, what's it supposed to do if you somehow manage to get the compiler to accept an abstract class as `T` ?

Answer (score 1):

To use generics at runtime you need to use reflection - look through all the types in the assembly for the one you want (you can use [Type.IsSubclassOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx)), get a [MethodInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx) for the generic method you want to call on it, then substitute in the actual type you want to call it on with [MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx), and call it using [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Bad idea, which DerivedClass do you want to take ? What if there is more than one ? what if there is no DerivedClass ?

You may pass the type as class type parameter and not method type parameter :

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass<T> where T : MyAbstractClass<T>, new()
{
  T MyMethod() { return new T(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `MyGenericMethod` is an instance method:

```
var method = typeof(this).GetMethod("MyGenericMethod", Type.EmptyTypes);
method = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { FindDerivedClass(myAbstractClass) });
Action action = (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), this, method);
action();
```

If `MyGenericMethod` is a static method:

```
var method = typeof(TypeWithGenericMethod).GetMethod("MyGenericMethod", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
method = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { FindDerivedClass(myAbstractClass) });
Action action = (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), method);
action();
```

If `MyGenericMethod` returns a value, then use `Func<ReturnType>` in place of the `Action` delegate.